# Complexity of backtracking to find power set given random array of numbers

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, backtracking

Given an array of elements which can contain duplicates, this is an algorithm that solves the problem.

```
def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    
    nums.sort()
    res = [[]]
    self.dfs(nums, res, [], 0)
    return res

def dfs(self, nums, res, path, index):

    if path not in res:
        res.append(path)
    
    for pos in range(index, len(nums)):
        self.dfs(nums, res, path + [nums[pos]], pos+1)
```

I think the time complexity of this algorithm is: $n \cdot n! \cdot  2^{n}$,

My logic is as follows, we loop the array once per value i.e., $n$

For each loop the number of calls is $(n-1)!$ which is $n!$ complexity

Then there is a check if value in array in each call which has at most $2^n$ checks since thats when power set is complete but dupes are being checked

Combining them gives $n \cdot n! \cdot 2^n$

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you please write proper pseudocode for a better understanding of your logic. Thanks.

Comment: That is the simplest python code possible, pseduo would look exactly the same

Comment: If there are duplicates, why not remove the duplicate entries beforehand? Then you will not need this code part: "if path not in res:
        res.append(path)"

Comment: And shouldn't it be $n! \cdot 2^{n}$ instead of $n \cdot n! \cdot 2^{n}$?

Comment: I explained my logic above, I think it is n * n! since for all n values in array we traverse them in factor of n! * 2^n . We keep duplicate values since power set 122 has multiple 2 values in the power set

Comment: The real meat of the question I want to know is am I correct in saying this is an n! algorithm at all ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I was thinking it might be some factor of k^n instead of n! but when I wrote out my logic n! seemed more likely